# Save all changes at once - MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I need to run multiple inserts but only save changes to database at the very end. If any exception happens for any of the inserts, the previous inserts should not be saved as well. It's like all or nothing transaction.

I know that we can achieve this using Entity Framework, by calling _context.SaveChanges() outside the foreach loop of inserts. But, is there any option to do this easily with native SQL queries?

This existing project I am working on doesn't have Entity Framework setup. So, before I go the route of adding Entity Framework to this project, I just want to know if there is any other easy option to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: If the validation is complex, consider a staging table or even a temp table where you can perform all necessary validations.  Once you are satisfied, then it becomes a small matter to insert or reject.

Comment: Funny, I'd say that adding EF to a project *is* the easy option..

Comment: Please give an exact example of the code you have now, that you wish to upgrade to something that will implement an "all or nothing" behavior

Comment: @CaiusJard Not convinced. EF has substantial inefficiencies built in, and encourages extremely poor query strategies, such as "Select N+1" and "Select then Update then Select", it also doesn't support (out of the box) most analytical functions. Often the most performant and easy to maintain solutions are based around stored procedures, where the DBA can ensure that queries are efficient. Obviously this applies to a bigger enterprise system, for a small-scale app EF does make life easier

Comment: The question is *is there any option to do this easily with native SQL queries?* This is not related to Entity Framework nor ASP.Net, so I removed these tags. It's not clear how you want to run this "native SQL".

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL Stored Procedure, assuming use of SQL server:

```
--@insertdata could be of type xml or json depending on your version
--of sql server and use it to do all inserts
--in any case, you can set as many parameters as you need to do the work
@insertdata xml = null

Begin Try
    --Begin Tran
    BEGIN TRAN

    --Do INSERTS

    --Commit the Transaction
    COMMIT TRAN
End Try

BEGIN Catch
    --If we have an exception
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

    --Return the ErrorMessage
    --SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()

    --OR as suggested, THROW so the exception is raised
    THROW
END Catch
```

Answer (score -1):

what you are looking for is `Transactions`,

"A transaction is the logical work unit that performs a single activity or multiple activities in a database. Transactions may consist of a single read, write, delete, or update operations or a combination of these."

learn more [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/transactions-in-sql-server-for-beginners/)  and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Mmm, mostly this is a link only answer and most people would have just made it a comment. Please extend it